# How to limit the permissions of a token?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarlint-intellij

My developers are making use of the [IntelliJ SonarLint plugin](https://www.sonarlint.org/intellij/) to connect to our SonarQube server and perform local analysis

To connect to the server they need to provide a token, so I want to create a single token which can be shared across all developers. I want this token to have minimal privileges i.e. to only allow the download of rules to allow local analysis to work.

If I generate a token as a SonarQube administrator, does this mean that the token has more privileges than a token generated by a non-admin user? The [SonarQube documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE43/Web+Service+API) implies any token has the ability to execute the full list of SonarQube Web Services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A token you create has all your privileges. Neither is it possible to gain privileges by using a token instead of username/password, nor to restrict a tokens' privileges. In SonarQube tokens and username/password are much alike - both tell the server who you are and what you are allowed to do.

A solution in your case might be:

1. Create a new, technical user, that only has very limited privileges. Use a password, that only YOU know
2. Login as that user
3. Create a bunch of tokens, one for each developer, with the developer's name as token name
4. Give each developer his/her own token
5. Whenever a developer leaves the company, invalidate his/her token

Comment: Thanks so much for the fast reply - this is exactly what I needed to know